# SELECTing the total count of multiple cells based upon a shared ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases, one holds family names and the other holds family members.

Since separate family names (lastnames) can be shared between people not related, they are assigned a family "ID" which is shared across both databases.

```
familyNames : lastName  | ID

memberNames : firstName | ID
```

I want to count how many members each family has, the output looking like:

```
Family Name | Members
----------------------
Johnson     | 14
----------------------
Brown       | 21
----------------------
White       | 33
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a new column? Thanks.

(The familyNames holds many more columns that are irrelevant to the problem, hence the reason to have two tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select f.lastname, count(m.firstname) as cnt
from familynames f
left join membernames m on m.id = f.id
group by f.id, f.lastname  
order by f.lastname
```

Answer (score 2):

HERE Database names are prefixed to table names , DB1, DB2 are database names.

```
SELECT FN.lastName as 'Family Name', COUNT(*) as Members FROM 
DB1.familyNames FN
JOIN DB2.memberNames MN
on FN.ID = MN.ID
group by FN.lastName
```